# A URI scheme name 'pack' already has a registered custom parser

Tags: c#-4.0, nunit

I am newborn to NUNIT test,facing error as 'A URI scheme name 'pack' already has a registered custom parser'.

```
[SetUp]
public void OnTestInitialize()
{
    UriParser.Register(new GenericUriParser(
    GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1);
    EncodeDecode = new EncodeDecodeSeNoSensorModes();
}
[TestCase(1,1,SSTAvail.no,3)]
[TestCase(0, 0, SSTAvail.no, 3)]
[TestCase(0, 1, SSTAvail.no, 0)]
[TestCase(0, 2, SSTAvail.no, 0)]
public void DecodeModeTest(int input1,int input2,SSTAvail Input3,int ExpectedResult)
{
    int OutputResult;

    //act 
    OutputResult = EncodeDecode.DecodeMode(input1,input2,Input3);

    // assert  
    NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(OutputResult, ExpectedResult);
}
```

If I run one test I am not facing issue. If run all test ended up this error

Comment: I've added an answer, but more context would be helpful. What is the code you're testing doing? It might make more sense for *that* code to be registering the parse. (As an aside, I'd also strongly recommend that you follow .NET naming conventions and use `using` directives appropriately - your test could be a lot easier to read.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added condition check forwhether the parser for a scheme is registered, only once.

```
if (!UriParser.IsKnownScheme("pack"))
                UriParser.Register(new GenericUriParser(GenericUriParserOptions.GenericAuthority), "pack", -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well presumably `OnTestInitialize` is currently being called once per test, but you want `UriParser.Register` to be called once *in total*. That's the sort of thing that makes sense to do in a static initializer, which is guaranteed to be run exactly once per AppDomain.

On the other hand, if your `EncodeDecodeSeNoSensorModes` class is meant to be dealing with the `pack` URI scheme, perhaps *that's* the class that should have the static initializer... it's not really clear what your code is doing.

Comment: Thanks for response.'Well presumably you OnTestInitialize is being called once per test, but you want UriParser.Register to be called once in total.' theses word help me lot.